# VBA to check if any cell is not blank in given range

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that will throw a prompt when a particular sheet is empty before saving the workbook.

Purpose of code: To check, if value of drop-down is "yes" in Main Sheet and if "yes", check if given range on a particular sheet is blank. If "yes", throw a prompt and change the drop down value to "No" on main sheet.

Concern: `For loop` in the code will check if any cell is empty in given range, instead, I want a code to check if there is an entry in any one cell in given range. Lets say given range is `E10:G19`, if we have an entry in E10, It should come out of the code and should not throw a prompt and should throw only if all the cells in given range is empty.

Question: What should replace my `For loop` that can serve my purpose?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim Rvalue As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set Rvalue = Sheets("Uni-corp").Range("E10:G19")

If Worksheets("Main").Range("E29").Value = "YES" Then
For Each cell In Rvalue
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            bOk = True
            Exit For
        Else: bOk = False
        End If
Next

If bOk Then
    If MsgBox("Sheet is blank", vbOKCancel + vbInformation) = vbOK Then
    Worksheets("Main").Range("E29").Value = "NO"
    Cancel = True
    End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're after something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)    
    If UCase(Worksheets("Main").Range("E29").Value) <> "YES" Then Exit Sub
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Uni-corp").Range("E10:G19")) > 0 Then Exit Sub
    If MsgBox("Sheet is blank", vbOKCancel + vbInformation) = vbOK Then
        Worksheets("Main").Range("E29").Value = "NO"
        Cancel = True '<--| this will make the macro not save the workbook
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function b_is_range_empty(my_rng As Range)

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(my_rng) > 0 Then
        b_is_range_empty = False
    Else
        b_is_range_empty = True
    End If

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print b_is_range_empty(Selection)

End Sub
```

The idea is to use the built-in formula in Excel - CountA. It is optimized for faster search. In the test it works with selection of the area.

Edit:
In stead of this:

```
For Each cell In Rvalue
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            bOk = True
            Exit For
        Else: bOk = False
        End If
Next
```

Write simply this:
`bOK = b_is_range_empty(Rvalue)`

Comment: thank you. I am afraid, now i am even more confused on how to replace my requirement in your code. I am not that good in VBA :-(

Comment: b_is_range_empty returns a boolean value - true or false, depending whether the range is empty. Paste my code in a separate model, select some range and run TestMe to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim Rvalue As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set Rvalue = Sheets("Uni-corp").Range("E10:G19")

If Worksheets("Main").Range("E29").Value = "YES" Then
For Each cell In Rvalue
        If IsEmpty(cell)<>true Then
            bOk = false
            Exit For
        Else: bOk = true
        End If
Next

If bOk Then
    If MsgBox("Sheet is blank", vbOKCancel + vbInformation) = vbOK Then
    Worksheets("Main").Range("E29").Value = "NO"
    Cancel = True
    End If
End If

If bOk=false Then
    If MsgBox("Sheet is not blank", vbOKCancel + vbInformation) = vbOK Then
    Worksheets("Main").Range("E29").Value = "Yes"
    Cancel = True
    End If
End If

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am afriad, its not what I am looking for. Code will still check for each cell in Rvalue. `For Each cell In Rvalue`

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be exiting your for loop when the first cell is empty, you will want it to only exit when it finds a value instead:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim Rvalue As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set Rvalue = Sheets("Uni-corp").Range("E10:G19")

If Worksheets("Main").Range("E29").Value = "YES" Then
For Each cell In Rvalue
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            bOk = True
            'Exit For moved to Else section
        Else: bOk = False
        Exit for
        End If
Next

If bOk Then
    If MsgBox("Sheet is blank", vbOKCancel + vbInformation) = vbOK Then
    Worksheets("Main").Range("E29").Value = "NO"
    Cancel = True
    End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```